# Permutations of the word ENGLAND such that permutations start and end with a vowel

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

> How many words can be made by using the letters of the word ENGLAND such that words begin and end with a vowel?

I couldn't understand how come the answer to this question is $120$.

Comment: Please indicate what you have tried and where you are having trouble.

Comment: Are you looking for anagrams of ENGLAND? (i.e. using seven letters, and using precisely the same letters - no double-E for example)? At the moment the problem is not sufficiently specified.

Answer (score 6):

$7$ letters.

> $1)$ $2$ vowels, so $2$ choices.
>
> $2)$ $5$ consonants, so $5$ choices here.
>
> $3)$ $4$ consonants left, so $4$ choices here.
>
> $4)$ $3$ consonants left, so $3$ choices here.
>
> $5)$ $2$ consonants left, so $2$ choices here.
>
> $6)$ $1$ consonant left, so only $1$ choice here.
>
> $7)$ $1$ vowel left, so $1$ choice here.

$$2*5*4*3*2*1*1=240$$

Divide by $2!$, because there are two $N$'s.

$$\frac{240}{2!}=120$$